# activate deactivate status using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to activate and deactivate a category status from the admin side if user is active, then show that category in front side.

How can I activate and deactivate categories?

I want a button to click active and deactivate categories from the admin side.

**Controller Code:-**

```php
function update_status(){

    if(isset($_REQUEST['svalue']))
    {
        $this->load->model('categorymodel','category');    
        $set_status=$this->category->update_status();
        if($set_status>0){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message',"category has been updated.");
        }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message',"category has not been updated.");
        }

    }
    return redirect("admin/category");
}
```

**Model Code:-**

```
function update_status(){
    $sid=$_REQUEST['sid'];
    $svalue=$_REQUEST['svalue'];

    if ($svalue=='active') {
        $status='inactive';
    } else {
        $status='active';
    }
    $data = array(
        'status' => $status
    );
    $this->db->where('id',$sid);
    return $this->db->update('category',$data);                
}
```

**View Part:-**

```
<td>
    <?php
        $status = $data->status;
        if ($status == 'active') {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/category/update_status?sid=<?php echo $data->id;?>svalue=<?php echo $data->status; ?>" class="btn btn-success">Active</a>
    <?php
        } else {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/category/update_status?sid=<?php echo $data->id;?>svalue=<?php echo $data->status;?>" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</td>
```

**Database Table:-**

```
Id              Primary int(11)     
category_name           varchar(255)        
slug                    varchar(255)    
category_image          text    
created_at              timestamp       
updated_at              datetime        
status                  enum('inactive', 'active')
```

Comment: You want to activate / deactivate users but the code that you have posted is relaetd to category. Could you please post correct code.

Comment: Well, I am very sorry for that, but want to activate deactivate category.

Comment: ok, np. Do you have a View where you are showing the listing of all the categories. If  yes, can you paste the view.

Comment: <td>

<?php $status = $data->status; if ($status == 'active') {?>
 
 <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/category/update_status?sid=<?php echo $data->id;?>?svalue=<?php echo $data->status;?>" class="btn btn success">Active</a>

<?php } else {?>

<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/category/update_status?svalue=<?php  echo $data->status;?>" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a> 

<?php  }  ?>   

<td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have following code in View.

```
<td> 
    <?php $status = $data->status; 
    if ($status == 'active') {?> 
        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/category/update_status?sid=<?php echo $data->id;?>?svalue=<?php echo $data->status;?>" class="btn btn success">Active</a> 
    <?php } else {?> 
        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/category/update_status?svalue=<?php echo $data->status;?>" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a> 
    <?php } ?> 
<td>
```

You should change as below

```
<td> 
    <?php $status = $data->status; 
    if ($status == 'active') {?> 
        <a title="Click to Deactivate" href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/category/update_status?sid=<?php echo $data->id;?>&svalue=inactive" class="btn btn success">Active</a> 
    <?php } else {?> 
        <a title="Click to Activate" href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/category/update_status?sid=<?php echo $data->id;?>&svalue=active" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a> 
    <?php } ?> 
<td>
```