# Controller data not passed to Model | Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im creating a Active/Inactive status button for my page.But the data from the controller is not sent to the Model.

This is my code.

**Controller  Banner.php**

```
public function banner_list()
 {

    $data['title'] = "Banner Type List";
    $session = $this->session->userdata('username');
    if(empty($session)){ 
        redirect('admin/');
    }

    $this->load->view("admin/banner/banner_list", $data);

    // Datatables Variables
    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));


    $bannertype = $this->Banner_model->get_bannertypes();
    //echo json_encode($bannertype);
    $data = array();

    foreach($bannertype->result() as $r) {

$status = $r->status;
$btn = "";

if($status=="active") {

    $btn =   '<a href="<?php
    echo base_url();
?>admin/banner/update_status?sid=<?php
    echo $r->banner_id;
?>&svalue=inactive" class="btn btn-success">Active</a>' ;

} else {

    $btn =  ' <a href="<?php
    echo base_url();
?>admin/banner/update_status?sid=<?php
    echo $r->banner_id;
?>&svalue=active"
class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a>' ;

}

    $data[] = array(

        $r->banner_url,
        $r->banner_name,
        $r->display_image,
        $btn,


            // '<button type="button" id="status_checks" class="status_checks btn-success" value="$r->status">"'.$r->status.'" </button>',
        '<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xs"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".edit-modal-data"  data-banner_id="'. $r->banner_id . '"><span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span></button></span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xs delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".delete-modal" data-record-id="'. $r->banner_id . '"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button></span>',

    );
  }

  $output = array(
       "draw" => $draw,
         "recordsTotal" => $bannertype->num_rows(),
         "recordsFiltered" => $bannertype->num_rows(),
         "data" => $data
    );
  echo json_encode($output);
  exit();
 }
```

**Model Banner_model.php**

```
function update_status(){
          $sid=$_REQUEST['banner_id'];
          $svalue=$_REQUEST['svalue'];

          if($svalue=='active'){
              $status='inactive';
          }else{
              $status='active';
          }
          $data= array(
                    'status' => $status
                      );
         $this->db->where('banner_id',$sid);
         return $this->db->update('banner_types',$data);                
         }
```

**Views banner/banner_list.php**

```
    <?php

?>

    <?php $session = $this->session->userdata('username');?>
    <div class="row m-b-1 animated fadeInRight">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="box-content card white ">
  <h4 class="box-title">ADD NEW banner TYPE </h4>


      <div class="card-body">
        <?php $attributes = array('name' => 'add_banner', 'id' => 'xin-form', 'autocomplete' => 'off');?>
        <?php $hidden = array('user_id' => $session['user_id']);?>
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/banner/add_banner', $attributes, $hidden);?>
        <div class="form-body">


          <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="name">URL</label>
           <input class="form-control" placeholder="banner Name" name="banner_url" type="text" value="">
          </div>


            <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="name"> Name</label>
           <input class="form-control" placeholder=" Stitching Charge" name="banner_name" type="text" value="">
          </div>

           <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="name">Banner Image </label>

           <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="design_image" name="design_image" onchange="readURL(this);">
           <small>Upload files only: gif,png,jpg,jpeg</small>
          </div>

        </div> 
        <div class="form-actions"> <?php echo form_button(array('name' => 'hrsale_form', 'type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'content' => '<i class="fa fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Save')); ?> </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card">
      <h4 class="card-header"> List All banner Types </h6>
      <div class="card-datatable table-responsive">
        <table class="datatables-demo table table-striped table-bordered" id="xin_table">
          <thead>
            <tr>


              <th>URL</th>
              <th>Banner Name</th>
              <th>Action</th>
               <th>Image</th>
               <th>Action</th>


            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The active inactive status is displayed correctly. But the status is not getting updated and in console there are no errors.

I followed this for my reference [activate deactivate status using codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450126/activate-deactivate-status-using-codeigniter)

Comment: are you doing this with AJAX?, if yes: please add relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You cant call model's function "update_status" directly from url.

[image]

To make it work, you should create a controller function and call that model function from there, don't worry about the $_REQUEST it will still carry it for the model function to use.

**on your Controller Banner.php**

```
function update_status(){ // You only neeed to add thiss
   $this->Banner_model->update_status();
}
```

And you can use it as like

**on your View**

```
  // and lastly update your view with this as link
  <?php echo base_url().'banner/update_status'; ?>?sid=0&svalue=0
```

**Note:**
If you do update processes. It would be easier if your view is in a "form" tag and submit it to your controller function, from there you prepare the variables and process the query by calling the model function. This will be more organized.

What you are doing is a bit messy, but it will still depends on the situation to know what is best to do, you'll just need to gather all the possible options and solutions.

Comment: How should be my controller look like?

Comment: Please see the answer again i added some notes.